# Stop responsive design from triggering on desktop

Tags: responsive

Please have a look at this website, digikala.com, and kindly let me know why it is not responsive when you resize your browser window on desktop while it is completely responsive when you are on a phone. I have noticed Google.com functions in the same way; when you are on a phone you see the mobile design whereas you cannot see the mobile design by resizing the browser on desktops.

Thanks

Comment: Here is another website with a similar behaviour: tennisworldusa.org

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

You need to add this code in head tag. its will work for responsive. use media query

```
/* Tablet Landscape */

@media screen and (max-width: 1060px) {
    #primary { width:67%; }
    #secondary { width:30%; margin-left:3%;}  
}

/* Tabled Portrait */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #primary { width:100%; }
    #secondary { width:100%; margin:0; border:none; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

because of responsive meta tag add this meta tag in head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14389343)

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">